# Loading Highcharts data via ajax removes Datalabels

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I have a HighCharts bar chart that gets its data populated from an ajax call like so.

```
var updateChart = function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/theurl/theid",
                type: "Get",
                success: function(data) {
                    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(data.SomeText);
                    chart.series[0].setData(data.SomeData, true);
                    chart.series[1].setData(data.OtherData, true);
                }
            });
        };
```

The chart is built up like so

```
var chart;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(
                {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'bar',
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        height: 750
                    }, ... (more options removed for brevity),                
                    plotOptions: {
                        series: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true,
                                format: '{y} %',
                                style: {
                                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                                    color: '#3b3b3b',
                                    fontSize: '125%'
                                },
                                useHTML: true
                            }
                        },
                        bar: {
                            dataLabels: {
                                enabled: true
                            },
                        }
                    },
                  ... (more options removed for brevity)
            );
        });
```

The idea is that the data in the chart will be updated dynamically every 10 seconds and reloading the entire page is not an option.

The data is loaded and the chart displayed only when I run updateChart() from the console. 
The first time I execute updateChart() everything is looks fine, however the second time I execute it (without reloading the page) everything appears except for the dataLabels which should be showing the percentage (100%, 55% etc.)

If I remove the useHTML = true option from the plotOptions.Series.DataLabels the percentage is again displayed but it introduces other styling issues that i was using the useHtml option to fix.

Is there a way to have useHTML set to true and not have the dataLabels disappear when updated?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it works fine, see: http://jsfiddle.net/2Gbja/2/

```
$("#b").click(function() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.xAxis[0].setCategories([Math.random(), Math.random()], false);
    chart.series[0].setData([Math.random(), Math.random()], false);
    chart.series[1].setData([Math.random(), Math.random()], true); //redraw chart once
});

$('#container').highcharts({

    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },

    series: [{
        data: [10, 20]
    },{
        data: [10, 20]
    }]
});
```

Note: redraw chart only once, so there is set `false` for redraw and only last one have `true`.